# How do I create countdown timer using PHP or Jquery For Stored Time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

```
<?php
$time=time();
$time_out=$time-60*24;

if($userInfo['deleteTime'] < $time_out){
?>
    <td><small class="showExpire">Timeout..You Cannot Reverse the Deleted Request</small></td>
<?php } else { ?>
    <td><a href="#" rel="<?php echo $userInfo['reqID']; ?>" class="cancelDelete"><small>Cancel Deleting Request</small></a></td>
<?php }?>
```

this is static script and want to make compatible with my code

```
<script language="JavaScript">
TargetDate = "12/27/2017 10:56 PM";
BackColor = "palegreen";
ForeColor = "navy";
CountActive = true;
CountStepper = -1;
LeadingZero = true;
DisplayFormat = "%%D%% Days, %%H%% Hours, %%M%% Minutes, %%S%% Seconds.";
FinishMessage = "It is finally here!";
</script>
```

when user delete something then
I gave him 24 hrs to reverse his delete and before 24hrs get completed then i have shown cancel Delete button and if 24 hrs are done from the time he deleted then he will not be able to reverse the delete and has shown Timeout message. But now i m not able to put 24 hour countdown for that user when he will delete then he should know that he left x time to reverse his delete 
how do i use countdown for this logic

Comment: You need to store the deleted time in database  and use JavaScript for countdown timer on browser. And whenever user opts to reverse action check if the reverse time - deleted time is less than 24 hrs

Comment: Find the difference between deleted time and current time And check that is less than 24 hrs  or not

Comment: yes i have stored deleted time in db with column name deletedTime and i have used that in my above cod in if condition

Comment: You can create a cron job that continues to check for the time of 24 hrs, once its over the cron removes the option of deleting

Comment: hmmm i have used but i m not able to make it compatible with this code which is dynamic

Comment: any one here for my question ????? @Rahul

Comment: ok do you know how to use ajax and jquery @AbhishekBurkule

Comment: not much but i know php alot

Comment: but if it can be done with php then still it is fine not important to be done using ajax or jquery @Rahul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this using jquery,ajax and php as

```
<script>
    setInterval(countDownTimer, 1000); // call your function at regular interval of time

    function countDownTimer()
    {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'your php file path',
            method : 'get',
            success : function(response)
            {
            if(response.errCode == 0)
            {
                $('your table id').append("<td><small class="showExpire">Timeout..You Cannot Reverse the Deleted Request</small></td>")
            } else
            {
                $('your table id').append("<td><a href="#" rel=response.reqId class="cancelDelete"><small>Cancel Deleting Request</small></a></td>");
            }
            },
        })
    }
</script>

// in php file
<?php
$time=time();
$time_out=$time-60*24;

if($userInfo['deleteTime'] < $time_out){
    return response()->json(['reqId'=>'your id']);
} else {
    return response()->json(['errCode'=>0]);
}
```

Comment: their are 4 error code you suggested on append both lines and in php code response both the lines

Comment: Suddenly that error occur for mi while using it in my main query